# How to find out what is wrong in test case during importing it to TFS 2010

Tags: testcase

I'm importing test cases from xml file to TFS2010 and get an exception. But there is no info about what definitely is incorrect.

```
"Work item 0 is invalid and cannot be saved. Exception: 'TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save'."
```

How is it possible to determine what is wrong in imported data from xml?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
  using System.Xml;
  using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
  using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
  using System;
  using System.Linq;

  internal class Program
  {
    // Input File
    private static TestLink testLink = new TestLink("E:\\dev\\TestLinkToTfs\\testsuites.xml");

    // Target TFS server
    private static Tfs tfs = new Tfs("http://host:8080/tfs/Test", "Test");

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testLinkTestCase = testLink.GetTestCases().Take(1).ToList();
        var steps = testLinkTestCase.Descendants("step");
        var testCase = tfs.Project.TestCases.Create(tfs.Project.WitProject.WorkItemTypes["Test Case"]);
        testCase.Title = testLinkTestCase.Attribute("name").Value;

        var summary = testLinkTestCase.Descendants("summary").ToList();
        var issueId = TestLink.GetLinkedIssueId(summary);

        var regEx = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        var grandParentName = regEx.Replace(testLinkTestCase.Parent.Parent.Attribute("name").Value, string.Empty);
        var parentName = regEx.Replace(testLinkTestCase.Parent.Attribute("name").Value, string.Empty);

        var area = string.Format(@"Test\Test Cases\{0}\{1}", grandParentName, parentName);

        testCase.CustomFields["Assigned To"].Value = string.Empty;
        testCase.Area = area;

        Tfs.AddSteps(steps, testCase);

        testCase.Save();
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the Work Item id is 0 means that this is created dynamically and some field values are not valid. You should try the method

```
workitem.validate();
```

before you save the Work Item and then try to debug you code. This will tell you the exact fields that have invalid data.
I could be more helpful if you post the code and the xml that you use for this.

Comment: I can't share you my code but please look at the debug process http://screencast.com/t/std7wbETLYt  
Please suggest what do I look for?

Comment: I need too many photos to dig down to your work item.But I have a solution for you. I don't know if you are familiar with the Watch window but I will try to be as simple as I can. Here is an image where I use the Watch http://postimg.org/image/srt2pl0gn/. If the count is !=0 then it means that the work item has a field with invalid value. 
If you expand one object(in my example 0) there you can see the name of the field that has invalid data.
The easiest way to find the proper values with this field is to make a new test case in Visual Studio and then see the available values

Comment: I suppose I use Validate() incorrect.
     testCase.WorkItem.Validate();

What is 'workitem' in your context?

Comment: I have TestCase object testCase but it doesn't have Validate() method. Only testCase.WorkItem.Validate() is possible. 
So I don't have such elements as you have during debug.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. This http://postimg.org/image/6p21pqm59/ is an image of another piece of code that I used the same way as you do.
Please take also a look at this video about debug https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCPt9aOcd98